# Should questions that violate API Terms of Service be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, legal

Question is here: [How to remove or hide powered by text from Google Translate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24281192/1235702)

I've commented to let the user know this is violating Google's TOS, but I was wondering if this should be flagged?

As @gunr2171 pointed out, the TOS for StackExchange (understandably) state:

> Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer
>   network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, transfer or
>   store illegal material including that are deemed threatening or
>   obscene, or engage in any kind of illegal activity is expressly
>   prohibited.

However, as many of the comments here have noted, there (also understandably) seems to be a precedent about not policing third parties' policies: [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors)

It seems like this is a contradiction. I appreciate everyone's contributions and just want to know  which way to go when this kind of thing happens in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: From the [TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal) for this site: "Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, transfer or store illegal material including that are deemed threatening or obscene, **or engage in any kind of illegal activity** is expressly prohibited."

Comment: I would vote to close as "off topic > This question appears off-topic because it intentionally tries to violate a 3rd party's TOS." I just need someone to back me up and I'll do it.

Comment: Aww come on, where's dat hacker spirit !!!

Comment: That said, we're not responsible for policing other companies' Terms of Service.  Questions like this can always be re-phrased in some way that doesn't identify the target company being abused.

Comment: Fair enough, but shouldn't people looking for this kind of information at least be made aware that it's illegal? (Assuming the best here...)

Comment: @RobertHarvey True, but in this case, it would more be upholding the SE Terms, as Gunr points out in their first comment.

Comment: Same answer as for enforcing NDAs http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors

Comment: I dunno, don't programs like AdBlock basically do the similar thing?

Comment: @Coffee: When you browse a random website on the Internet, you don't enter into a legal agreement with the company who owns the website, requiring you to see the ads.  That's not the case here.

Comment: @Coffee Yes, probably. But that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so you're saying no, don't bother flagging it? I don't see it as policing, rather informing people. As long as they realize that what they're doing is illegal, it's totally up to them what they do from that point.

Comment: You already informed people when you posted the comment below the question.

Comment: True enough. My question is should I have done more, for future reference. I'm sorry, I'm just confused about what the official policy of this site is. I'm not suggesting a change. @gunr2171's comment suggests that I should flag it; your comments seem to say that I shouldn't?

Comment: I would close it just to discourage more people from answering as well as similar questions in the future. In no way am I suggesting that what you should _always do_. That's why I haven't VTC yet.

Comment: Google's terms of service aren't laws, guys.

Comment: But AFAIK they are legally binding? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_service

Comment: BTW, I'm not trying to be argumentative; I'm just trying to figure this out. I should have known this would be a confusing topic given the legal ramifications.

Comment: Just as we cannot expect moderators to judge the factual correctness of an answer, we cannot expect them to judge the legal compliance of a question with various contracts. Mods are simply not qualified and not trained for this kind of question. The correct people to make that call would most likely be the stackexchange lawyer team; and the correct person to contact them is IMO only someone with standing in this case I.e. Google's lawyers

Comment: @HugoRune Excellent point! That clears this up for me; thanks!

Comment: @CullenJ Just because they may be binding in the US, does not mean they are binding in every Stackoverflow user's country (or does it?)

Comment: Besides, what if the user is asking for "research" purposes? Surely researching various "hacking" techniques is not guaranteed to be bad? I myself did a lot of research into virus writing when I wrote a virus scanner...

Comment: In many jurisdictions, "violating" TOS is not illegal - it could be breach of contract, if the other party thought so (but that would be a civil matter). But then again in many jurisdictions, a TOS would only be a valid contract if someone had explicitly accepted it. StackOverflow is a worldwide site, so as long as the question itself is not illegal I would just warn the OP that the topic of the question is questionable.

Comment: I am not sure if asking how to kill a person makes you a killer and the question illegal. Well, unless the user actually performs the action, he would not be breaching the TOS of the company. Why asking such a question makes it illegal. Also, you might feel like not answering the question on ethical grounds but does it still make asking the question as performing an illegal action? I wonder regarding the technicality.

Comment: Forget flagging, call the cops!

Comment: This isn't really the same as the case with NDAs. In that case, you can argue that the question should be closed because it's very unlikely anybody could answer the question without violating an NDA, and therefore the question just isn't useful to SO. In this case, many people might be able to answer without violating anything, which makes the case for closing much weaker.

Comment: It's definitely worth adding a comment saying that their code will probably be violating the TOS, and Google may (and historically sometimes has) intentionally break their code for doing so, and that there's an official way that Google wants you to do this that's a whole lot easier, and so on. And if you want to conclude, "And therefore, I'm not going to answer this, and don't be surprised if no one else does", that seems reasonable. But insisting that it be closed, I'm not sure about.

Comment: You can't be sure if the person is bound by the TOS. Maybe local jurisdiction makes the TOS illegal. Maybe he's a penetration tester with contract not affected by TOS or something. Actually, he may not be aware this is forbidden, so the answer can actually be "don't do it."

Comment: @Shakti Just for information, asking how to kill someone *is* actually illegal in many jurisdictions - e.g. in the UK (anti-terror legislation).

Comment: @MarkJ - Well, I understand. Just was trying to draw a parallel. May be I picked up not the best example there is. But hope you get the point.

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh sure, possibly I was being too niggly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think we've exhausted this topic in the comments at this point, so I'm posting the answer that was reached in the comments.

**TL;DR: Not our responsibility, so informing them and leaving it alone is the best we can do.**

I really liked how [HugoRune](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145999/hugorune) [put it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274906/should-questions-that-violate-api-terms-of-service-be-flagged#comment108062_274906), so I'm copying their comment here:

> Just as we cannot expect moderators to judge the factual correctness of an answer, we cannot expect them to judge the legal compliance of a question with various contracts. Mods are simply not qualified and not trained for this kind of question. The correct people to make that call would most likely be the stackexchange lawyer team; and the correct person to contact them is IMO only someone with standing in this case I.e. Google's lawyers