# Questions with the express purpose to attempt to subvert any form of security or IP protection should be handled a special way

Tags: feature-request

I keep coming across questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846094/how-can-%C4%B1-receive-captcha-using-php-curl

Now I doubt the question will get any attention, but I feel there should be a flagging option specifically for this that also hides the question as there have been instances where I have seen people post nearly complete code to brute force sites such as Facebook that took far too long to take down so the code could not be used by others.

I think that a option to flag for the reason of violating a TOS should be added and any such questions should be removed (hidden) from public eye until a trustee has a chance to declare the question safe thus marking it visible, or unsafe thus permanently removing it and possibly applying a punitive or restrictive action against the poster.

Obviously such system could be circumvented by the poster making his question specific enough as to hide his true intent, I just dont feel that we should make it this easy.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Should questions that violate API Terms of Service be flagged?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274906/1114), [How do we handle questions that are potentially or blatantly illegal or malicious?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267699/1114), [What to do with a question about how to do something that violates 3rd party Terms of Service?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139024/134300)

Comment: I've written captcha-breaking code before. I didn't use it for spammy purposes -- rather, I used it to demonstrate that the captcha was incredibly weak, and argue with the developers for replacing it with a better one. The line between educational use and malicious use is often unclear without context that we don't have.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Agreed, the example easily falls into a grey zone, but as I mentioned there have been instances where the intentions were clear, usually posted by new "anonymous" accounts, the question gets put on hold quick enough, by is still visible and damaging code still in the open.

Comment: @JeremyBanks also agree that there are perfectly legit reasons to break security systems, but the code and specifics to do so should not be allowed on SO. Companies pay people to try to break their security all the time, but when they do or get close, they dont allow the info to be published.

Comment: I partially agree. There are cases where the question asker *does* provide enough context to make it clear that they have malicious intent (perhaps by showing us the specific site they're targeting). I often downvote, VTC and VTD such questions. We also sometimes benefit from the fact that such questions are often asked by people who don't/can't bother to formulate an on-topic question. ;)

Answer (score 10):

It is not our job to enforce the Terms of Service of *any* company. If a user is violating the Terms of Service of Stack Exchange, we have moderators and community managers. If a user is violating the Terms of Service of another entity, well, it's their terms. They need to deal with it.

We are not the police of the development community. We aren't the emergency call center. At best, we are the nosy neighbor that watches through closed blinds and grumbles about *that one guy* across the street. There are many, many, reasons a user may want to do something "suspicious", but that doesn't mean it if up to us to deal with it. It also doesn't mean they *are* violating any terms. We simply don't know and don't have the authority to enforce them.

We agreed to the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](//stackexchange.com/legal). If those aren't being violated and you don't like the question, I suggest you down vote the question and move on. If the question is poorly written, flag it accordingly (unclear, too broad, opinion based, lack of code, recommend a tool).

Comment: Way to not read the OP... You basically seem to have skipped the whole thing.

Comment: "I think that a option to flag for the reason of violating a TOS should be added and any such questions should be removed (hidden) from public eye until a trustee has a chance to declare the question safe thus marking it visible" - I believe that is the crux of what you are asking for, no? My response is telling you that is not appropriate. We are not here to determine if something violates the terms of service for other sites.

Comment: And what about this sites TOS? "Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security encryption codes".

Comment: Are you an employee of Stack Exchange? Are you provided compensation *by* Stack Exchange to enforce *their* terms of service? If not, then it is not your job to enforce them. It is your job to adhere to the terms. It is not your position to ensure that others are doing the same.

Comment: That's a weak argument; then why the flagging system at all?