# Should an aggressive reply on a question asking to go against ToC's be punished?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this is the best place for this but here goes.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382055/how-can-i-get-an-ipa-file-off-my-phone-onto-my-computer) was recently asked on Stack Overflow (now deleted). The question was about how to download an IPA from an iPhone to a computer. I asked why as it seemed to be a bit dodgy. The reply was along the lines of "I want to modify it for personal use".

After this reply, I responded with a simple "That's probably against the app's (or appstore's) terms and conditions (ToC's)" to  which I was met with a hostile response (see picture below). The question was deleted before I could flag it.

> [image: Screen grab after deletion.]
>
> [image: Aggressive reply]

The question was about going against ToC's of the app/appstore and the user clearly didn't seem to care.

My question is, should this behavior be punished?

Comment: What punishment are you proposing? We find out where he lives, go round and tell him he's very naughty or something else? The account is deleted so there isn't much else we could reasonably do is there?

Comment: that would explain why i couldnt find his account when i searched for it. lets assume the account is active for the purpose of this question, i would suggest an account ban for a few days, a week maybe

Comment: @RobertLongson back in the days Jeff used to do [house visits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/158100), maybe that can be re-instated?

Comment: We do not enforce other people's contracts. The rudeness is actionable, though.

Comment: [Should questions that violate API terms of service be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274906) and compare [How do we handle questions that are potentially or blatantly illegal or malicious?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267721/)

Comment: [Off Topic] What is a ToC?  I'm familiar with ToS's but not ToC's

Comment: Terms and Conditions, i typically write ToC's for short, not sure why its not TaC's though

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I've seen it as T&C and some people just shorten it to "the Terms".

Comment: very true, ill remember for next time

Comment: with regards to that specific comment, you could just flag it and observe how it disappears immediately [as explained eg here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266162/839601). One of the words that trigger immediate comment deletion after a single flag is "sh!t"

Comment: You pushed the right button and the troll popped out.  Well done.

Comment: There's nothing against the terms of service about that -- you've just jumped down a user's throat over nothing. IIRC, iTunes used to download IPA files to the computer while performing a phone backup.

Comment: @duskwuff but the user wanted to download the IPA file to modify it. That seems like its against ToC's

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reply contains some profanity, so you could flag it as *"No longer needed"*, as it really adds nothing to the question.
I personally wouldn't choose for *"Rude / Abusive"*, since it's not that bad, but it has to be deleted.

The question itself was extremely poorly written, off topic, and in general shouldn't be on SO. If the user hadn't deleted it himself, it would've been a good idea to close-vote (/down / delete-vote) it.

But now that both the question and the account are deleted: _*Shrug*, case closed.

Comment: so pretty much treat it as any other off topic question? shouldnt there be some punishment for a question to go against ToC's as well as profanity in replies? assuming the account was still active?

Comment: Basically, yes. SO does not enforce another company's ToC. If someone wants to ask a question about scraping a website, for example, we can only tell them the site probably won't like that.

Comment: right, ok, thanks for the clarification