# Can I flag a question which solely involves code that's used to break the ToS of another service?

Tags: discussion

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525474/discord-bot-to-selfbot) in the `discord.js` tag trying to ask for help with code creating self-bots, which is against the Discord ToS.

> Automating normal user accounts (generally called "self-bots") outside of the OAuth2/bot API is forbidden, and can result in an account termination if found.

They used plenty of winky-face emojis in their question, so I'm sure they knew what they were doing and how it violated the Discord ToS. I was wondering if I can flag the post "in need of moderator attention" for that, or if I should just downvote and walk away.

Comment: Such questions should be closed and deleted ASAP.  That should ensure that SO users, and SO itself, is shielded from any subsequent legal actions, (IANAL).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274906/should-questions-that-violate-api-terms-of-service-be-flagged